# Differences of mins Proof

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Consider real numbers $x$ and $y$. Prove the following:

$$\min(x,y)-min(0,x+y)=min(|x|,|y|)sgn(x)sgn(y)$$

I am not even sure how to start the problem. Maybe using $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the different cases. Suppose $x,y>0$. Then the equality is trivial. If $x>0,y<0$, then there are again two cases: $|x|>|y|$ or the other way around. You can check that for both cases the equality holds. Then the fourth case is $y,x<0$, where checking the minimums again yields that the equation is correct.